# Convert function from wchar_t array to long int

Tags: c++, c, unicode, encoding

I'm writing a function that converts a `wchar_t` array to `long integer` values (the function ignores spaces beetwen digits). Look at my code:

```
long wchartol(wchar_t *strArray, long retVal = 0) {
  wchar_t *firstArray = strArray;
  long pow;
  int count, i;
  count = 0;
  i = 0;
  pow = 1;
  while(*firstArray != L'\0') {
    //firstArray++;
    if(*firstArray++ == L' ')continue;
    count++;
  }
  firstArray--;
  while(i < count) {
    if(*firstArray != L' ') {
      retVal += (*firstArray - L'0') * pow;
      pow*=10;
      i++;
    }
    firstArray--;
  }
  return retVal;
}
```

I have another funny problem: when I copy digit data (it contains spaces) from some file and paste it into the function's argument, I get wrong data returned by the function; but when I replace these spaces with spaces typed in the keyboard, all works great. What's the reason? I invoke the function this way:

```
std::wcout << wchartol(L"30 237 740") << std::endl;
```

Reading a file written using `outputstream.imbue(std::locale::global(std::locale("")));` Maybe that's the reason?

Comment: Perhaps the file you pipe in doesn't contain wide chars. (Or would it automatically be converted? I wouldn't think so...) Please check if wchartol("30 237 740") returns the same incorrect value, if so that's obviously the problem. Also, the string from the file may contain newline characters, you should stop processing when you encounter any non-numerical character other than space (in the line while(*firstArrax != L'\0'))

Comment: You want L"30 237 740" to return 30237740?

Answer (score 1):

Your code assumes that the input string consists of digits and spaces only, terminated by null-character. It is possible that piping in a file will end the string with newline and then null. As a result you count '\r' and '\n' as digits, subtracting '0' from them and increasing the pow accordingly.

Please try `std::wcout << wchartol(L"30 237 740\r\n") << std::endl;` and see if it produces the same incorrect value.

Edit: Here is some code that doesn't make any assumptions about the string, it will just ignore any spaces when concatenating the first integer in the string, if there is one.
It sets the pointer to the position just after the first char that is neither a digit nor a space and concatenates all digits from there to the start of the string:

```
// move pointer to position after last character to be processed
while( (*firstArray >= L'0' && *firstArray <= L'9')* ||
        *firstArray == L' ')
  firstArray++;

// process all digits until start of string is reached
while(firstArray > strArray) {
  firstArray--;
  if(*firstArray >= L'0' && *firstArray <= L'9') {
    retVal += (*firstArray - L'0') * pow;
    pow*=10;
  }
}
```

(disclaimer: I didn't test this code, so use on own risk)

Comment: I forget to say that this function use only for file with known structure. It doesn't contain any escape sequence. Data in it file there are data that i've wrote before. I've wrote to this file using std::wcout.imbue(std::locale::global(std::locale("")));, maybe it has reason?

Comment: have you tried stepping through your program with the debugger? That's the best way to make sure your string looks as you expect.

Comment: @StevenS I've debuged it, type of strArray is L"30 237 740"

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use wstringstream?

```
wifstream in(...);
wstringstream ss;

wchar_t ch;
in >> ch;
while (in)
{
    if (ch != L' ')
        ss << ch;

    in >> ch;
}

long number;
ss >> number;
```

As for the problem with the file, it might be that the file's encoding is not Unicode. Try opening the file with a text editor and telling it to store the file as Unicode.

Comment: You said that it does work with input from the console (or from the "keyboard", whatever you meant by that), didn't you? Then if it doesn't work with the file it must be that the file's encoding is not Unicode.

Comment: when i change space pasted into IDE (into function argument) to spaces typed by me (into this IDE) it works.

Comment: OK, still. The file's encoding is not Unicode. Try changing it as I described. Are you using Windows? If so, open the file with Notepad and go to **File -> Save as...**. Then, at the bottom of the dialog, set the **Encoding** setting to **Unicode**.

Comment: no it ANSI, but i've wrote to tjis file using outputstream.imbue(std::locale::global(std::locale("")));

Answer (score 0):

This loop is wrong

```
while(*firstArray != L'\0')
{
    firstArray++;
    if(*firstArray == L' ')continue;
    count++;
}
```

since you increment before you test therfore a space at the start of the string won't be found. I assume you meant this

```
while(*firstArray != L'\0')
{
    if(*firstArray++ == L' ')continue;
    count++;
}
```

Comment: In this case, if the first character is not a space, it will still be skipped. What you mean is to put `firstArray++` completely after the `if`. That means the `firstArray--` after the loop should also be removed.

Comment: It's not that the space at the start won't be found, it's that he is adding 1 to the count for the null character and ignoring the first character no matter what it is. The fix here is correct.

Comment: @john I use it, but this doesn't help